# Disable dictation feature Ctrl+D

Tags: 16.04, command-line, shortcuts

When I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> I get this dictation-like mic in my screen:

[image]

I would like to disable this shortcut, because I need it in the terminal for other applications.

However, I can not find the shortcut in the keyboard settings, or anywhere else.

Comment: What Ubuntu version and flavour are you using?

Comment: This looks shockingly like Mac OS X. If it actually is Mac, the kind people over on [apple.SE] will be able to help much better than us.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this command to disable the action:

```
trap "" 3
```

To go back to default you should use:

```
trap " " 3
```

In this example `date` is called when you press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>:

```
trap "date" 3
```

`kill -l` gives you a list of signals.